# Using Google Tag Manager in Firebase instead of GTAG

Tags: firebase, google-analytics, google-tag-manager

I am kind of confused with all this Google Analytics Services and I have an issue in my app.

My application is using Firebase, and we currently have an integration with Google Analytics.
This produce the following GTAG

```
<script src="https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?l=dataLayer&amp;id=G-XXXXXXXXX" async=""></script>
```

when we deploy our app.

From what I understand, this is using a `GTAG` which is an tag that can be used in `Google Tag Manager` but it is not actually a `Google Tag Manager` script.

Now, we have a `Google Tag Manager` account that we would like to use to enable tracking in Google Analytics and Azure Clarity. The problem, from what I see [here](https://www.analyticsmania.com/post/gtag-vs-google-tag-manager/) is that we should not be using a `Google Tag Manager` and a `GTAG` together.

But I can't find a place in firebase where we use a `Google Tag Manager` account instead of a GTAG, and turning of the GTAG would cause feature like A/B testing to be unavailable.

My question is, is there a way to use GTM directly from firebase, or how can I proceed with this integration ?

Comment: As far as I am concerned, you should not use your Google Tag Manager (GTM) from firebase, you just need to have your measurementId from the firebase setting and assign this to the same field in GTM while creating  GA4 configuration Tag. Finally instead of GTAG JS codes you should write GTM JS codes in your front-end.